# Plotting 3 inequations with 3 variables in maple

Tags: maple

I need to plot this in maple

```
3x1+y+z<=180
x<=12
x+y+4z<=190
```

How can I do a plot in Maple? I'm using Maple 13

Comment: I don't see how this is a programming question. I think this question is better suited to http://superuser.com

Comment: In Maple the boundaries between programming and using are blurry.

Comment: x1 in the first equation should be x I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You plot inequalities with the `inequal` command from the `plots` library, and you can plot multiple equations by putting them in brackets:

```
plots[inequal]([3x1+y+z<=180, x<=12, x+y+4z<=190])
```

If a given plot command doesn't support multiple plots, you can always do the plots separately and combine them with `display`:

```
with(plots):
plot1 := inequal(3x1+y+z<=180):
plot2 := inequal(x<=12):
plot3 := inequal(x+y+4z<=190):
display([plot1, plot2, plot3])
```

Comment: Plots:-Inequal only plots inequalities in 2 variables, see its Maple's help page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned these three inequalities are constraints for an optimization problem, therefore I assume you are interested in the intersection of them and not each separately. Here is how I do it. I use `piecewise` command to define a binary values function that is equal to 1 when the point satisfies all three inequalities and then I use `implicitplot3d` command from `plots` package and an inequality `f > 1/2` or you can go for the equality `f = 1`, then this command will plot the boundary of your region as a surface. Of course sometimes you may not get a suitable plot, for example one case happens when your region is tiny compared with the plotting box.

```
f := piecewise( And( 3*x + y + z <= 180, x <= 12, x + y + 4*z <= 190 ), 1, 0 );
plots:-implicitplot3d( f >= 1/2, x = -500..500, y=-300..700, z=-500..500, style = surface, grid = [50, 50, 50], color = blue, view = [-500..500, -300..700, -500..500 ] );
```

Here is the output.
[image]